# GitHub showcases API

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, github, github-api

Can anyone tell me what GitHub APIs I should use for retrieving GitHub showcases? Thanks.

- In order to get the list of GitHub [showcases](https://github.com/showcases/), what exact GitHub API should I use?
- After I select a topic, to retrieve the repos under the topic (e.g. [Made in Africa](https://github.com/showcases/made-in-africa)), what exact API should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API to list or GET a showcase.

I've taken a look and the closest you could get (which is still quite a bit far from your request) is to use the [GitHub Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories). However, a list like the one you suggested, [Made in Africa](https://github.com/showcases/made-in-africa) is completely curated and the parameters to get such results are not part of the search syntax, e.g. country of origin.

I'll keep an eye on this, and make sure to come back and correct the answer if anything changes.

Comment: I can imagine the search API may be used for this purpose, but not sure what query I should add so that I can retrieve the showcases.

Comment: I would ask another question for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

While Github does not yet offer a showcase API, there is a node package available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-explore that you can use to GET a showcase.

1. Get the module using npm

   ```
   npm install --save gh-explore
   ```
2. Query for the showcase

   ```
   const ghExplore = require('gh-explore');

   ghExplore.showcases.get({ showcase: 'made-in-africa' }, function (err, showcase) {
       console.log(showcase);
   });
   ```

Although the question is marked with javascript and node tags specifically I thought it pertinent to mention that I am developing a similar library to achieve this in python 3. You can refer to the repo here https://github.com/victorbordo/gh-showcases